# How can I move a widget block to the top of the content or sidebar area

Tags: static-block, widgets

I want to add a promo banner on my website. It's either in the content area or in the right sidebar. I thought it's good and easy to use static blocks and widgets.

It's easy to control where it comes and on which pages.

I have the problem now that the blocks are always at the bottom of these areas. It's on the bottom as the last element in the content area and in the sidebar. How can I change it In the xml so that these widgets are always as the first element ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the relevant template/layout code you are working on in your question?

Comment: I didn't change any code yet. I just use the widget and static blocks from magento enterprise 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. [Insert the static block using a layout XML update](http://bradfrost.com/blog/web/magento-static-blocks/) making use of `before="-"`.
2. [Create new widget targets in your layout so you can use the widget interface](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/482/20131).

Comment: I did this and set before="content". Do you know if its possible to show these widgets or static blocks only from a certain time to time?

Comment: @Thomas - probably better to make it a separate question.