# Magento Widget block refrence

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, widgets, local.xml, position

I want to display my custom block in the top of right column. I followed the below link

[Widget setup in backend - how do I move upwards](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59/widget-setup-in-backend-how-do-i-move-upwards/482#482)

I have a doubt in the second step,what is the [widget_id] specified?
How can I do it?

Here is my local.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">    
   <catalog_category_layered>        
        <update handle="subcategory_top_container" />
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <subcategory_top_container>
        <reference name="right">
           <block name="right_top" type="core/text_list" before="-" translate="label">
                <label>Right Column Top</label>
           </block>
        </reference>
   </subcategory_top_container>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `widget_id` specified is id of widget which you have to create (if not created) from admin **CMS->Widgets**

Comment: I am using cms/static_block type widget.

Comment: in your widget grid there is column named `widget_id` you will get value from there

Comment: Can I use this integer value in xml.

Comment: yes you  can use .

Comment: My widget id is 1. Is the following xml is correct?

<widgets>
    <1>
        <supported_blocks>
            <left_column_top>
                <block_name>left_top</block_name>
            </left_column_top>
         </supported_blocks>
    </1>
</widgets>

Comment: give it a try and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Yes its working. thank you Piyush Suthar.
Is there any other way to do this? ie,for all widgets

Comment: I don't know any other way.

Comment: you can mark the answer as accepted if it helped you